# add vertical space above and below figures/code chunks

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I am knitting from `Rmd` to PDF. I'd like to add vertical space above and below figures/code chunks to separate this content from body text. I've done this successfully for `Rnw` files by adding the following to my preamble [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425604/add-space-between-document-text-and-knitr-code-chunk-in-compiled-pdf):

```
\renewenvironment{knitrout}{\vspace{1em}}{\vspace{1em}}
```

I tried adding this line to `header-includes` in the yaml section of my Rmd file, but it did not work. I turned on the option to keep the interim tex file, and I see there is no `knitrout` environment in the tex.

Instead, (i) code chunks are wrapped in `\begin{Shaded}`, (ii) figures in `\begin{figure}`, and (iii) tables in `\begin{longtable}`.

I tried solving the problem for code chunks (i) by adding the following to `header-includes`:

```
\renewenvironment{Shaded}{\vspace{1em}}{\vspace{1em}}
```

This added space, but dropped the shaded background. I'm not sure how to fix this or address the figures (ii) and tables (iii).

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.4
```

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, @DavidLively. I've come across advice suggesting that questions like this are a better fit for SO because it would help to have someone who knows `rmarkdown` and LaTeX. You might be right though.

Comment: Fair enough. My LaTeX skills are way rusty. The question is fine here, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to modify hooks: https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/
I give you some examples. Once you understand how it works, you can add your own modifications.

## Add vspace before source code

The hook to be modified:

````
```{r setup_source, include=FALSE}
hook_source_def = knitr::knit_hooks$get('source')
knitr::knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  if (!is.null(options$vspaceecho)) {
    begin <- paste0("\\vspace{", options$vspaceecho, "}")
    stringr::str_c(begin, hook_source_def(x, options))
  } else {
    hook_source_def(x, options)
  }
})
```
````

How to call this modification:

````
```{r vspace, vspaceecho='2cm', echo=TRUE}
summary(cars)
```
````

## Add vspace after R output

The hook to be modified

````
```{r setup_output, include=FALSE}
hook_output_def = knitr::knit_hooks$get('output')
knitr::knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
  if (!is.null(options$vspaceout)) {
    end <- paste0("\\vspace{", options$vspaceout, "}")
    stringr::str_c(hook_output_def(x, options), end)
  } else {
    hook_output_def(x, options)
  }
})
```
````

How to call this modification:

````
```{r vspaceafter, vspaceout='1cm'}
summary(cars)
```
````

## Add vspace before and after a figure

You can create a new environment to embed a figure. This requires to add a trick to make pandoc ignore `\begin` and `\end`, otherwise pandoc do not consider code inside environment as markdown syntax.

### Create an external tex file to be called in YAML

This text inside

```
\newenvironment{plotspace}[1]{#1}
% -- command for pandoc trick with \begin and \end -- %
\newcommand{\nopandoc}[1]{#1}
```

### Call tex file in YAML

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    include:
      in_header: header.tex
```

### The hook function to include in your code

```
hook_plot_def = knitr::knit_hooks$get('plot')
knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options) {
  if (!is.null(options$vspaceplot)) {
    begin <- paste0("\\nopandoc{\\begin{plotspace}}\n\\vspace{", options$vspaceplot, "}\n")
    end <- paste0("\n\\vspace{", options$vspaceplot, "}\n\\nopandoc{\\end{plotspace}}")
    stringr::str_c(begin, hook_plot_def(x, options), end)
  } else {
    hook_plot_def(x, options)
  }
})
```

### How to call it

````
```{r plotvspace, vspaceplot='2em', fig.cap='Figure with vspace'}
plot(cars)
```
````

## Retrieve Shaded in a renew environment

As you tried to renew `Shaded` environment, you can do it as follows in your additional header.tex file.

```
\renewenvironment{Shaded}
{
  \vspace{2cm}%
  \begin{snugshade}%
}{%
  \end{snugshade}%
  \vspace{5cm}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @StatnMap. This looks great. I put the pandoc trick in the .tex file I call in YAML, but I'm getting an error. `! Undefined control sequence.
l.145 \newcommand{\nopandoc`. Should it be obvious that I am missing a latex package?

Comment: I dont think you need other package. I put the Rmd file and the header tex file to be downloaded (zipped) on my website : https://statnmap.com/vspace_rmarkdown/ . Unzip it. Then you can run it by clicking on the `knit` button in Rstudio or you can run it with this command in R : `rmarkdown::render("Fig_Vspace_rmarkdown.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document")`

Comment: i replaced my included .tex file with yours and solved the error, so thanks. everything runs, but i'm struggling to modify the space between sections. in [this rmd file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bgrl7ruzfnclu6/Fig_Vspace_rmarkdown_v2.Rmd?dl=0), i move the parameters to the setup chunk and set them to be very small...but the pdf output still shows big spaces.

Comment: It is because in the `\renewenvironment{Shaded}` set in the header tex file, there are also `vspace` set. You should choose between this renewenvironment and hook modifications. Or define the desired combination.

Comment: [I made a few tweaks](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3hbzdlspqscrk0v/vspace.zip?dl=0) to get the PDF looking just as I want. Really great. The only remaining issue I can see is that `vspaceplot` prevents figure labels from working. For instance, a reference to Figure 1 in the text prints as "Figure ??". Is it possible that the pandoc "trick" is interfering with figure numbering?

Comment: I use the "pandoc trick" with bookdown and references to figures without any problem, so I do not think this is a reason. Sometimes references with bookdown do not work only because there is a lack of spaces in the code. But I can not tell you more...

Comment: Thanks, @StatnMap. Posting here to document my attempts. Maybe it helps someone else. [I modified the markdown files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fjyvexey1u2rfm8/AAB98qfsfka401EdTAGF0J-Sa?dl=0) to use `bookdown::pdf_document2` and show (a) when I define `vspaceplot` in a chunk, the figure IS NOT numbered and (b) when I do not define `vspaceplot` the figure IS numbered.

Comment: @SébastienRochette following along a couple of years later and am unable to access your code at  statnmap.com/vspace_rmarkdown?

Comment: You can find it here: https://statnmap.com/files/Vspace_rmarkdown.zip