# Modifying space around a Knitr code chunk

Tags: r, knitr, rnw

Is it possible to modify the space around a specific KnitR code chunk within a .rnw file that is going to be weaved into a PDF.

There is a question and answer about changing the options globally...

[add space between document text and knitr code chunk in compiled pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425604/add-space-between-document-text-and-knitr-code-chunk-in-compiled-pdf)

...but I need to be able to do it on specific code chunks only.

In particular I need to reduce the vertical space located at the top of a code chunk so that an xtable prints on the line directly after some text.

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: have you tried setting the `table.placement` option within `print.xtable()` to "h!"?

Comment: @Sarina I hadn't actually tried that and it is a good answer but unfortunately it hasn't helped in my situation.